# Rewrite application path from tomcat using IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I need to configure an URL rewrite that way:

Server Application Provider: Tomcat 8 with a Java Web Based Application.
WebServer: IIS 10.0

Original URL application:
http://localhost:8080/Spigen

Desired URL:
http://localhost/Spigen/bi/sams

I tried that way:

**1-** In IIS 10 I set up a Server Farm with
    Server Address= localhost
    httpPort= 8080

**2-** Configured a Rule to remove 8080 port from URL:
[Rule 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpRVB.png)

**3-** Configured a Rule of user-friendly URL:
[user friendly config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ2tP.png)

I didn't have desired effect. When I access:
http://localhost/Spigen/bi/sams
I receive from browser 404 messagem:
[404 message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VnUB.png)

I don't really have idea how could I get that.
The idea is to have several URL acessing the same application and the application make decisions based on it.

URL Examples:
/Spigen/bi/sams 
/Spigen/bi/app 
/Spigen/bi/nok

What configuration is missing?